# Animating an image over another image in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, cabasicanimation

So basically i have two image objects, 1 portrays a line and the other a circle. I wanted to know if its possible using something like CABasicAnimation to loop the line image across the x axis but still keeping it within the circle image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this with either `CABasicAnimation` or `UIView` animation.

`CAAnimations` only operate on `CALayer`s, and they are rather tricky to use. I suggest using UIView animations on `UIImageView`s or other UIViews instead. You could even set up a custom subclass of `UIView` to have a CAShapeLayer as it's backing layer and then animate the custom `UIView` using UIVIew animations